# Accessing container with name in custom bridge network

Tags: docker, docker-network

I created custom bridge network as:

```
docker network create test
```

I am running Mongo DB image in this network with following command:

```
docker run -d -p 27018:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=test -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --net test --name=testdb mongo
```

This created container and I'm able to connect to this from robo3T.

Now I ran mongo-express image in same network with following command and trying to above DB:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=test -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27108 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=testdb --net test --name=mongo-ex mongo-express
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [testb:27018] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND testdb
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: I don't see you specifying the network in either of your `docker run` commands.

Comment: Even if I give --net test in both commands, it's not working

Comment: After debugging figured out that, if I run on default port (27017), it's working. But any other port, it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between containers on a shared docker network, you access the port of the container directly. Publishing the port, with the `-p 27018:27017` option, creates a port forward from the host on 27018 into the container on port 27017. The publish is visible to those outside connecting to the host, but does not change the port the container sees itself internally, or how other containers connect over shared networks.

Also note if you do not wish for those external to docker to access the container port, there's no need to publish to allow access between containers on the shared network.